Kafka Consumer concurrency across multiple instances - How many consumers will be created?
I understand that we can set Kafka container concurrency and it will create n number of consumers.
My application has 4 instances running with same consumer group id. If I set the container concurrency to 6, Will I be having 4 x 6 = 24 consumer running in mu application or will it be just 6 consumers spread across the 4 instances ?

My understanding is that concurrency is per instance, so 24... You should be able to verify with kafka-consumer-groups command

The number of consumers will be created as many as you requested. The question is how many of them are going to be active according to the number of partitions all of them are subscribed. This is exactly a purpose of the consumer group feature in Apache Kafka: only one consumer per partition - all others are idle until consumer group rebalance happens.

Thanks for the reply. The question was actually about the number of consumers that will be created. If I request for 6 consumers in one instance using container concurrency, And I have 4 instances of the application running. How many consumers will be created ? Consider that I have enough partitions for all the consumers.

Right. All the requested consumers are going to be created: concurrency * instances.

@ArtemBilan A follow up question: I have a topic having 16 partitions, 2 consumer instances with concurrency = 10 for the same consumer group. When boot app starts, 10 consumers are seen in each instance, totally 10*2=20, in the application logs. So far so good. However, the Confluent UI says the topic only has 10 clients. I thought it should be 16 clients across the two instances (with 4 idle ones not showing). Why it looks like the 10 concurrency is the total for the consumer group across two instances?
